# Passing a struct into a generic function in C

Tags: c

I declare a new struct with the name of "Struct"
I have a generic function that takes in an argument "void *data".

```
void Foo(void *data)
```

I pass an instance of "Struct" into the generic function.

```
Struct s;
Foo(&s);
```

I want to access one of the properties of the struct in the function.

```
void Foo(void *data) {
    char *word = (char*) data.word;
}
```

It's not allowed because it doesn't recognize data as a valid struct.

I even try to declare the data as the struct type first, and I get an error.

```
void Foo(void *data) {
    Struct s = (Struct) data;
    char *word = s.word;
}
```

I get "conversion to non-scalar type requested".

Comment: If you need it to be a Struct, why pass a void* in the first place?!

Comment: @Bo: The function could be a callback function that has to conform to an externally specified API, the caller and the function would know what is supposed to be in `void *data` but the code in between might not. See `bsearch` and `qsort` for examples from the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should turn on your compiler's warning flags (all of them). Then you should pass a pointer to your `Struct` and use something other than `struct` as a variable name:

```
Struct s;
Foo(&s);
```

Then, in `Foo`:

```
void Foo(void *data) {
    Struct *s    = data;
    char   *word = s->word;
}
```

You can't convert non-pointer types to and from `void*` like you're trying to, converting pointer types to and from `void*` is, on the other hand, valid.

Comment: all of them? That's a bit too much ... for example, in gcc the option `-Wwrite-strings` makes gcc a compiler for a language similar to, but not quite, `C` :)

Comment: @pmg: All of them (and `-Werror` too!) until you can clearly explain which ones can be dropped and why :) When you can snatch this warning switch from hand Grasshopper, you will be ready.

Comment: I just counted the `-W` options in my most demanding gcc alias: 58 of them (I may have made a counting mistake or two) ... including `-Werror` but not `-Wwrite-strings` :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a pointer to you struct and get a pointer to the struct inside the function:

```
Struct struct;
Foo(&struct);

void Foo(void *data) {
    Struct* struct = (Struct*) data;
    char *word = struct->word;
}
```

Comment: Also, use `struct Struct struct`.

Comment: The cast to `(Struct*)` is unnecessary. Some people do like to include it, but I believe it's better not to, because it prevents the compiler warning you if you attempt to assign a non-void pointer to the local variable.

Comment: Oh, and also: `struct` is a reserved word - choose another name for the local variable. @Radek: Not if `Struct` is the name of a typedef.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `->` operator when requesting structure member via pointer.

This should work: `char *word = (char*) data->word;`

You also have to pass the address of the structure to the function. Like this: `Foo(&struct);`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to call the function correctly:

```
Struct s;
Foo(&s);
```

Notice you're now passing a pointer to the structure.

Now, the function has to *know* that you're using a `Struct` (as opposed to something else) - perhaps because of another parameter, or a global variable, or some other reason. Then inside the function you can do:

```
void Foo(void *data) {
    Struct *structpointer = p; /* Note - no need for a cast here */


    /* (determine whether data does refer to a pointer then...) */
    char *word = structpointer->word;
    /* ... then use 'word'... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is pointer, so whatever you cast it to must also be a pointer. If you said `Struct* myStruct = (Struct*) data`, all would be well with the world.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing pointers and data.

`Struct struct` defines a data object
`void *data` expects `data` to be a pointer.

Call `Foo` with a pointer to a `Struct`, and make other necessary changes

Answer (score 0):

```
Struct struct;
Foo((void*)&struct);

void Foo(void *data) {
    Struct *struct = (Struct*)data;
    char *word = struct->word;
}
```

or the more compact form:

```
Struct struct;
Foo((void*)&struct);

void Foo(void *data) {
    char *word = ((Struct*)data)->word;        
}
```